# How to Join two select statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have four tables. I wrote 2 queries independently and those are working. But what I want to do is join those two queries and generate one result.

Here is my code

Query #1

```
SELECT 
    pm.DATE
    ,pm.customer
    ,pm.gp_no AS Gatepass_Num
    ,pf.style
    ,pf.color
    ,pf.batch_no
    ,COUNT(pf.roll_no) AS Roll_QTY
    ,SUM(pf.meter) AS QTY
FROM
    (packinglists_fabrics_items pf
     ,packinglists_main pm 
WHERE 
    pf.p_id = pm.id 
    [AND pm.date between {DateR,RANGE1} and {DateR,RANGE2}] 
    [AND pm.customer_id = "{factory,false}"]
GROUP BY 
    pm.DATE, pm.gp_no, pf.style, pf.color, pf.batch_no)
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT 
    lo.DATE
    ,lo.customer_name
    ,flo.style
    ,flo.color
    ,flo.batch_no
    ,COUNT(flo.rowno) AS Roll_QTY
    ,SUM(flo.meter) AS QTY_Meter
FROM
    loadinglists_fabrics_items flo, loadinglists lo
WHERE 
    flo.p_id = lo.id 
    [AND lo.date between {DateR,RANGE1} and {DateR,RANGE2}] 
    [AND lo.customer_id = "{factory,false}"]
GROUP BY 
    lo.DATE, flo.style, flo.color, flo.batch_no
```

`batch_no` is unique for `loadinglists_fabrics_items` table and `packinglists_fabrics_items` table

Result of query 1

[image]

Result of query 2

[image]

Expected output

[image]

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Combine how? Show is some sample data, and the combined result!

Comment: Try to format your queries. Edit, mark code, click `{}`.

Comment: Always simplify your code. you don't have to include every single field of your query. Ask question, get the idea and solution, apply on your problem.

Comment: @jarlh i have update the question with some outputs.have a look

Answer (score 2):

Try like this, I assume that you are using SQL Server

```
SELECT A.*
    ,B.*
FROM (
    SELECT pm.DATE
        ,pm.customer
        ,pm.gp_no AS Gatepass_Num
        ,pf.style
        ,pf.color
        ,pf.batch_no
        ,COUNT(pf.roll_no) AS Roll_QTY
        ,SUM(pf.meter) AS QTY
    FROM packinglists_fabrics_items pf
        ,packinglists_main pm
    WHERE pf.p_id = pm.id
        AND pm.DATE BETWEEN {DateR
                ,RANGE1}
            AND {DateR
                ,RANGE2}
        AND pm.customer_id = "{factory,false}"
    GROUP BY pm.DATE
        ,pm.gp_no
        ,pf.style
        ,pf.color
        ,pf.batch_no
    ) A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT lo.DATE
        ,lo.customer_name
        ,flo.style
        ,flo.color
        ,flo.batch_no
        ,COUNT(flo.rowno) AS Roll_QTY
        ,SUM(flo.meter) AS QTY_Meter
    FROM loadinglists_fabrics_items flo
        ,loadinglists lo
    WHERE flo.p_id = lo.id
        AND lo.DATE BETWEEN {DateR
                ,RANGE1}
            AND {DateR
                ,RANGE2}
        AND lo.customer_id = "{factory,false}"
    GROUP BY lo.DATE
        ,flo.style
        ,flo.color
        ,flo.batch_no
    ) B ON A.batch_no = B.batch_no
```